# finding and replacing a tree node in C#

Tags: c#, treeview

I have a treeview in my C# code. I want to replace all existing occurences of a tree node with a different text in my entire treeview upon a button click.

For Example, I have 3 occurences of a node with 'Text' as "Manual". I want to replace all of these 3 nodes with the text "Automatic". The problem is that these 3 nodes are under 3 different branches in the treeview. They do not share the same parent node. I intend to write to make this process automatic by writing a for loop but I dont understand how to find the required 3 nodes in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using recursivity.

Of course this is an exemple and you would need to remove the myTree declaration and use your tree but this should get you started.

```
private void replaceInTreeView()
{
    TreeView myTree = new TreeView();
    ReplaceTextInAllNodes(myTree.Nodes, "REPLACEME", "WITHME");
}

private void ReplaceTextInAllNodes(TreeNodeCollection treeNodes, string textToReplace, string newText)
{
    foreach(TreeNode aNode in treeNodes)
    {
        aNode.Text = aNode.Text.Replace(textToReplace, newText);

        if(aNode.ChildNodes.Count > 0)
            ReplaceTextInAllNodes(aNode.ChildNodes, textToReplace, newText);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It gives an error for aNode.ChildNodes.Count:

'System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode' does not contain a definition for 'ChildNodes'

What version of C# are you using?

Comment: I am using FrameWork 3.5 and I believe that on Framework 1.1 you can use Nodes See documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode_members(VS.71).aspx