# How to replace TreeNode in TreeView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I did it like this:

```
myTreeView.Nodes[foo] = newTreeNode.Clone(); // this doesn't work
```

I am wondering, how to do it right ?

EDIT:
I am thinking about delete old and insert new tree node.

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336756/finding-and-replacing-a-tree-node-in-c-sharp

Comment: @MUG4N, I need to replace TreeNode object and not only property

Comment: @William remove the old one and add the new

Comment: @L.B, I was thinking about this, *but Is there the only way to do that ?*

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
TreeNode node = myTreeView.Nodes[foo];
int index = myTreeView.Nodes.IndexOf(node);
myTreeView.Nodes.RemoveAt(index);
myTreeView.Nodes.Insert(index, newTreeNode);
```